# What is best way to identify HTML elements

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, regex

Im going straight to the point with simple situation. Here is example table on MySQL database.

**SQL Database**

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | Description |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | Example 1   |
|  2 | Example 2   |
|  3 | Example 3   |
|  4 | Example 4   |
+----+-------------+
```

And then i use PHP (Laravel framework) to get that data from database to my view.

**Laravel**

```
@foreach
  <div id="entry_{{ $table->id }}">
     <input type="text" id="description_{{ $table->description }}">
     <button id="save_{{ $table->id }}" class="button">Save</button>
     <button id="delete_{{ $table->id }}" class="button">Delete</button>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

And now we have whole database content in HTML view. For better user experience i need to use jQuery to tricks on fly, so i check when ever any button is pressed.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $(".button").click(function() 
  {
    // Get's id of button what is pressed
    var elementID = this.id;

    // I don't know if this regexp works, but you get the point. 
    // Let's grab all text before and after _
    var regexp = /(.*?)_(.*?)/;
    var match = elementID.match(regexp);
    var operation = match[1];
    var id = match[2];

    // And here i would check that is operation save or delete. 
    // If it is delete_2, i would do tricks with AJAX and after that delete div entry_2
  });
});
```

My question is that is there better way for naming/identifying HTML elements, so that i would not have to use regexp and matching to do tricks? This works and i have used this, but if there is better way i would like to learn it.

Comment: That works, but I'd use `this.id.split("_")` instead of a regex match. Alternatively, you can use `data-action="delete" data-id="2"` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

you can have your buttons like this:

```
<button name="{{$table->id}}" class="button save">Save</button>
<button name="{{$table->id}}" class="button delete">Delete</button>
```

and then you can use selector like below to avoid regex:

```
$(".save").click(function() {
    var id = this.attr('name');
});

$(".delete").click(function() {
    var id = this.attr('name');
});
```

Comment: In this case two buttons get the same id

Answer (score 1):

When handling with IDs, try to store that ID only on the most outer element that wraps any items related to that ID. If you repeat the ID as in your example, you'll have to read it from each element instead of just reading it once from the DOM. This approach is less error prone.

```
<div class="entry" data-entry-id="{{ $table->id }}">
   <input type="text" class="description">
   <button class="save button">Save</button>
   <button class="delete button">Delete</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
/* iterate over each entry */
jQuery( '.entry' ).each( function() {

  var entryId = parseInt( this.dataset.entryId );

  /* setup click handler for the buttons inside the entry */
  jQuery( this ).on( 'click', 'button', function( event ) {

    if( event.target.classList.contains( 'save' ) ) {
      // save here
      saveEntry( entryId );
    }
    else if( event.target.classList.contains( 'delete' ) ) {
      // delete here
      deleteEntry( entryId );
    }

  } );

} );
```

Please note that `dataset` and `classList` are plain JS APIs and work onthe DOM elements instead of the jQuery objects. See also:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList

Comment: This is nicest way so far, but my question is that now when my input's doesn't have unique identifier, how i can access to input value that is under data-entry-id X and it contains class "description"?

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one class in an element. I suggest adding them like below and changing id to data-id to contain only the row id:

```
<button data-id="{{ $table->id }}" class="button action-save">Save</button>
<button data-id="{{ $table->id }}" class="button action-delete">Delete</button>
```

Then you can check the action with jQuery's hasClass method:

```
$(".button").click(function() 
  {
    var id = this.attr('data-id'); // contains pure id
    if ($(this).hasClass("action-delete")) {
        // delete operation
    } else iif ($(this).hasClass("action-save")) {
        // save action
    } 
  });
```